# unexpected characters in the first column of my data frame from a .csv Pandas (EDITED AT BOTTOM)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I had an excel spreadsheet that I saved as a .csv file and now i'm trying to use it in python.  I have had several problems, but was able to sneak around them with parameters in the pd.read_csv() function.

Now it prints the data frame, but the first column header has two goofy characters attached to the front of it.  ÿþName is what it shows.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the encoding, or my csv file is poorly made.

It also gives me a key error when I try to set an index.

code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create main data frame from .csv

data_file = pd.read_csv("C://...........//8_29_2018.csv", engine='python', sep='delimiter', encoding='latin_1')

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_file)
#df1.set_index('Request Date')
print(df1.head())
```

Originally I tried just the file path, but I got this error.

```
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 539, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 767, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Then I tried encoding to utf-8 and got this error

```
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 539, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 767, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Not sure what to try now any help would be great.  Here is what my pycharm is printing with my code up top.

[image: CSV Print Out]

and here is what my csv file looks like when opened in excel

[image]

the red is just names that I don't want shared.

**EDIT:**  So my updated code is as follows and I'm getting a Key error when I try to set the index shown that is commented out. There is a picture in the comments below that shows the csv opened in notepad.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("C://Users..........//EXPORTED SPR PDM DATA//8_29_2018.csv", encoding='utf-16')
print(df1.head())
```

Result is:

```
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 876, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 891, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 945, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 932, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2112, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 26 fields in line 6, saw 28
```

Comment: try `utf-16`, it looks like you have [utf-16 BE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding) encoding based on the byte order mark

Comment: @EdChum That seemed to have cleaned it up, But it won't let me set the index that is commented out in my code above.  Any insight into that? it still says that there is a key error.

Comment: firstly `data_file` is already a df, no need for `df1`, secondly what does `print(data_file.columns.tolist())` show? you may have some whitespace or other weird non printing character

Comment: @EdChum [Here](https://imgur.com/a/H8Y3m1t) is the print out for that.

Comment: All your columns are being loaded into a single column, modify your `read_csv` line to this: `data_file = pd.read_csv("C://...........//8_29_2018.csv", encoding='utf-16')` your delimiter looks like it's a comma which is the default, no need to specify the engine unless there is a problem, you passed the string `'delimeter'` which doesn't make sense

Comment: @EdChum `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 26 fields in line 6, saw 28` I assume this is just a straight up problem with my csv file then?

Comment: Sorry but unless you post your actual code and data that others can reproduce, this becomes a fishing expedition and waste of time, am I supposed to guess the format of your data? The error is telling you that you have problematic format, so did you look at that line?

Comment: @Keizzerweiss open the file in a text editor like notepad to see the encoding

Comment: @EdChum [Here](https://imgur.com/a/n0Mcy94) is a pic of a notepad file.  Sorry guys I'm not allowed to share files outside the company.  I wish I could.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not going to assist without your data, you could easily anonymize it, and post something representative that reproduces your error.

Comment: @EdChum I got it. My cvs file was created as a .cvs (ms dos) vs .cvs utf-8